# Dense rank for counting distinct items using case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions, dense-rank

I have a table that looks similar to the one given below:

```
  comp_id      Item_id      Priority
   123456      123          1
   123456      321          1
   123456      333          2
   123456      334          3
   123456      334          3
   123456      337          4
   123457      339          1
```

I want to run a dense_rank function that will allow me to count distinct item_id, that have priority of (1 or 2). For the same comp_id, I would also like to give the same rank (distinct count) to the items that have have been assigned other priorities (e.g. 3 or 4).

Below is what I currently have:

```
(CASE WHEN Priority in (1,2) THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id, CASE WHEN Priority in (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ORDER BY item_id ASC )  END
 + CASE WHEN Priority in (1,2) THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id, CASE WHEN Priority in (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY item_id DESC) END
  - 1
  - CASE COUNT(item_id) OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id)
    WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id)
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END) as distinct_count
```

My current output:

```
  comp_id      Item_id      Priority     Dense_Rank (distinct_count)
   123456      123          1             3
   123456      321          1             3
   123456      333          2             3
   123456      334          3             NULL
   123456      334          3             NULL
   123456      337          4             NULL
   123457      339          1             1
```

My desired output is:

```
  comp_id      Item_id      Priority     Desired_Dense_Rank (distinct_count)
   123456      123          1             3
   123456      321          1             3
   123456      333          2             3
   123456      334          3             3
   123456      334          3             3
   123456      337          4             3
   123457      339          1             1
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. I'm using SQL server 2012

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your now completely unsupported old version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two levels of window functions: one to calculate the `DENSE_RANK`, and another to get the `MAX` of that rank. The second one will only partition by `comp_id`

```sql
SELECT *,
  distinctCount = MAX(dr) OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      dr = CASE WHEN Priority IN (1, 2) THEN 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id,
               IIF(Priority IN (1, 2), 1, 0) ORDER BY item_id)
           END
    FROM YourTable t
) t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nVKkff2c)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the code based on priority, but I didn't understand why  distinct count for other cases(3,4,...), why three is obtained, if it should be two (you have two unique Item_id  334,337 for comp_id=123456)

```
;with _lis as (

   select case when Priority in(1,2) then 'A' else 'B' end Pr,*  
  from tt
)
select *
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id,Pr ORDER BY item_id ASC) +
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY comp_id,Pr ORDER BY item_id DESC) - 1 
 from _lis
 order by comp_id,item_id,Priority
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying to get distinct item_id that have a priority of either 1 or 2 for every comp_id. Does your solution cater to this problem?

Comment: My code calculates distinct count item_id  for  based on grouping comp_id and ( priority(1,2) or other priority(3,4,....))

https://dbfiddle.uk/bS2DNX9h

Comment: Great thanks for the reply again. Your answer is close to what I wanted but not completely there yet. Thank you in any case and much appreciated!

Comment: your welcome, tell me if I can help to complete it or give a new data sample